# jQuery bootgrid Sorting function inconsistency

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm using jQuery bootgrid and its associated methods for my Table structure.

This issue is regarding the Column level sorting functionality of jQuery bootgrid.
Sort function works fine when there are numbers or alphabets.

But when there is a mix of lowercase and uppercase alphabets, Sorting doesn't happen correctly.

Eg: For `[Charity, peta, animals, Nature]`, the correct sorting order should be [animals, Charity, Nature, peta], irrespective of the letter case.

But bootgrid returns it as `[animals, peta, Charity, Nature]` - differentiating between lower and upper case.

How to fix this discrepancy in Bootgrid. Expecting response asap. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do custom sort like this:

```
function sortMyArray(arr)
{
    return arr.sort(function(a,b)
        {
            return a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase();
        });
}
```

Your issue happens because javascript compare strings by it's character codes comparation. Lowercase characters always have more weight over uppercase.

Comment: Looks good !! But can this be added to the bootgrid default column sorting function ?